# Error in startup of forest Meters: XDMP-BADSTARTUPTOKEN: Bad startup token for Forest Meters

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

We are getting below error while connect to meter forest

This forest is unavailable due to the following error:

> XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in startup of forest Meters: XDMP-BADSTARTUPTOKEN: Bad startup token for Forest Meters, 9100739 before last journal start 9100826

We looked around and found below Marklogic Article
[MarkLogic Knowledge Base](https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/messages/XDMP-en/XDMP-BADSTARTUPTOKEN)

It says
Delete both the label and journal files for the forest

AFAIK, deleting label is not a problem, it will again create label file once forest is restarted.
We are more worried about our files, data will be deleted? is there any option to retrieve these records after forest restart

What can be the reason behind this error?

Comment: It will be great if somebody can comment on this

Comment: Data is present in stands (generally files like 0001fb,00001fd etc) so I don't think data will get deleted if you delete journal or label file, You can disable the forests, go to forest directory, delete Journals, label files. Enable the forest again. Try testing it in lower environment before moving to production. Take backup for any DR.